# Android Icons in small ImageView not sharp

Tags: android, android-imageview

Hello I have a strange Problem.
In my project I am currently working on, I have rounded brand icons from various companies in my mipmap folders. When I use these icons in an ImageView with width and height = 24dp the edges aren't smooth and I can see pixels. I've already tried removing the lowest resolution version of my images but it stays the same. Putting them in the drawable folder doesn't work too.
So my question is how can I show for example the Facebook icon in an small ImageView with sharp edges?

All icons are png files.

Comment: What device / virtual device(s) are you loading them on? Are the images going blurry on multiple devises?

Comment: I am using a Moto G7 and that is the only phone I can test on. If I show the icons in an bigger ImageView everything is ok.

Comment: For testing I have tried with a vector version of a simple brand icon and it looks fine but the problem is that some of the icons are so complex and it would be a pain to covert them to vector assets.

Answer (score 0):

Use one more xml file and use radius, corner types size
and change your image

Comment: And how should this help me with my png icons?

Comment: use vector image.

Comment: As mentioned earlier, some of the icons are really complex.